# Laravel jetstream, no funciona el DialogModal que viene por defecto

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

jetstream trae varios componentes por defecto, estoy usando uno llamado: **DialogModal**, es un componente vue y es el siguiente:

```
<template>
    <modal :show="show" :max-width="maxWidth" :closeable="closeable" @close="close">
        <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <div class="text-lg">
                <slot name="title">
                </slot>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-4">
                <slot name="content">
                </slot>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="px-6 py-4 bg-gray-100 text-right">
            <slot name="footer">
            </slot>
        </div>
    </modal>
</template>

<script>
    import Modal from './Modal'

    export default {
        components: {
            Modal,
        },

        props: {
            show: {
                default: false
            },
            maxWidth: {
                default: '2xl'
            },
            closeable: {
                default: true
            },
        },

        methods: {
            close() {
                this.$emit('close')
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Me he hecho un layout.vue muy simple:

**SimpleLayout.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
        <nav class="bg-white border-b border-gray-100">
            <!-- Primary Navigation Menu -->
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="flex justify-between h-16">
                    <div class="flex">


                        <!-- Navigation Links -->
                        <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                            <jet-nav-link :href="route('home')" :active="$page.currentRouteName == 'home'">
                                Inicio
                            </jet-nav-link>
                            <jet-nav-link :href="route('user.index')" :active="$page.currentRouteName == 'user.index'">
                                Usuarios
                            </jet-nav-link>
                            <jet-nav-link :href="route('task.index')" :active="$page.currentRouteName == 'task.index'">
                                Tareas
                            </jet-nav-link>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <header class="bg-white shadow">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <slot name="header"></slot>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <main class="bg-white vh-100">
            <slot name="body"></slot>
        </main>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import JetApplicationLogo from './../Jetstream/ApplicationLogo'
    import JetApplicationMark from './../Jetstream/ApplicationMark'
    import JetDropdown from './../Jetstream/Dropdown'
    import JetDropdownLink from './../Jetstream/DropdownLink'
    import JetNavLink from './../Jetstream/NavLink'
    import JetResponsiveNavLink from './../Jetstream/ResponsiveNavLink'

    export default {
        components: {
            JetApplicationLogo,
            JetApplicationMark,
            JetDropdown,
            JetDropdownLink,
            JetNavLink,
            JetResponsiveNavLink,
        },

        data() {
            return {
            }
        },

        methods: {
        },

        computed: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

Luego tengo mi componente **user.vue**:

```
<template>
    <simple-layout>
        <template slot="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <h1 class="text-center">Usuarios</h1>
                        <button class="btn btn-success">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>

        <template slot="body">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(user,index) in users" :key="index">
                                {{user.name}}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">

                <dialog-modal :show="true">
                    <template v-slot:title>
                        <h2>Titutlo</h2>
                    </template>
                    <template v-slot:content>
                        <h2>Contenido</h2>
                    </template>
                </dialog-modal>

            </div>
        </template>
    </simple-layout>
</template>

<script>
    import SimpleLayout from './../Layouts/SimpleLayout'
    import DialogModal from './../Jetstream/DialogModal'


    export default {
        components: {
            SimpleLayout,
            DialogModal
        },
        props:['users'],
        data(){
            return{

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

En este ultimo es donde estoy intentado usar el **DialogModal** de JetStream pero no funciona.
Lo importo asi: **import DialogModal from './../Jetstream/DialogModal'**. 
Y lo uso asi :

```
  <dialog-modal :show="true">
                    <template v-slot:title>
                        <h2>Titutlo</h2>
                    </template>
                    <template v-slot:content>
                        <h2>Contenido</h2>
                    </template>
                </dialog-modal>
```

Pero recargo la pagina y no sale nada de este modal.
Añado tambien que no me da ningun error de compoenente no encontrado ni rutas de importacion erroneas, de hecho probe eso poniendo una letra de mas y si daba error por tanto es correcta la ruta de importacion